# setTimeout Function with Dynamic Duration

Tags: javascript

I have a setTimeout function that iterates over values:

```js
var content = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
var duration = ['10000', '10000', '20000', '10000', '30000']

for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("hi")
    }, duration[i])
}
```

However, the duration is not dynamic. I've also attempted `parseInt(duration[i])` but that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong here?

-------------Clarification-----------------:

As I understand it, the setTimeout() method "calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds"[1](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). As the abstract code above quite clearly suggests (though it may take more than a brief glance to determine), for each item in the `content` array, there are a set of operations that are performed. Each operation is associated with a duration of time, in milliseconds, that the current operation should wait until the next operation begins.

In the example above, upon initiating the function, the initial wait duration, 10000 milliseconds, which is the first item in the duration array, seems to called as expected. However, subsequent operations do not wait the duration specified by their respective value in the duration array.

Comment: *"However, the duration is not dynamic."* Can you elaborate on that? You are clearly passing different values to `setTimeout` (well, some of them at least). I'm relatively sure that JS will convert them to numbers automatically, but yeah, those should be numbers.

Comment: I converted your sample code to a runnable code snippet. It works just fine for me in Chrome (wait 30 seconds for the last alert dialog to show up).

Comment: don't pass a string to timeout.

Comment: Also works fine in Firefox 38...

Comment: Weird. This doesn't work for me in Chrome Version 40.0.2214.111 (64-bit) on Linux.

Comment: *"This doesn't work"* Maybe you simply have wrong expectations of what the code is doing. But since you *still* have *not* explained what behavior you expect, we can't really help you. If the code doesn't do what you want, you might just have written the wrong solution.

Comment: Although granted the OP failed to make it explicit, and gave the question a poor title, it seems a bit ingenuous to refuse to make the obvious (?) assumption that the intent is that the timeouts should run in sequence, or at least post a comment asking if that is the case. I don't see why this question should be closed or down-voted; it contains good material for talking about asynchronicity. If the goal of SO is to help people solve their problems, certainly helping them clarify and frame their questions, including suggesting what they might be missing, is one valuable aspect of that.

Comment: @torazaburo: If that really was the case, then this is a duplicate and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 3):

As another poster mentioned, you probably want each timeout to start from the end of the last one. You could use the suggested "recursive" approach, but **promises** would result in more readable code. First, we'll write a `wait` routine which returns a promise which resolves in some number of milliseconds:

```
function wait(n) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) { setTimeout( resolve, n); });
}
```

Now we can rewrite your loop as follows:

```
var promise = Promise.resolve();

for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    promise = promise . then(function() { return wait(duration[i]; });
}
```

We need the `Promise.resolve()` to kick things off with a promise which is already resolved. By the way, as a bonus, at the end of this loop you have a promise for the entire chain of timeouts having completed, which you can use to do something next.

It turns out that this is exactly the same as

```
duration.reduce(
    function(promise, ms) {
        return promise . then(function() { return wait(ms); });
    }, Promise.resolve()
);
```

If you don't know `reduce`, it's well worth learning.

But imagine how nice it would be to skip all this, and simply have something which instead of setting up a timeout, waits **right there**. It turns out you can in fact do this, using `async` functions:

```
async function wait_series(duration) {
^^^^^
    for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        await wait(duration[i]);
        ^^^^^
    }
}
```

Async functions will require using an appropriate transpiler, such as babel, with the appropriate flags.

If you don't have or want to use Babel, but do have access to **generators**, you could use a library like `co` to turn a generator (`function*`) into an asynchronous function, with `yield` where you want to wait:

```
function wait_series(duration) {
    co(function *() {
    ^^
        for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            yield wait(duration[i]);
            ^^^^^
        }
    });
}
```

The advantage of using async functions, or their `co`-based equivalent, is that you can go back to writing regular old `for` loops like you are used to. They essentially allow you to write asynchronous code with a synchronous mindset. You no longer have to think about promises (although `co` does its magic under the hood using them).

You may say that this seems like a lot of stuff to learn just to write a sequential series of timeouts. But actually, promises and async functions are **easier** in the end than writing timeouts which call functions which then set up other timeouts.

#### Recursive solution

If you prefer the recursive solution, here is a slightly streamlined version of it, that also actually works (by invoking `loop` the first time via the `()` at the end):

```
function wait_series(duration) {
    var i = duration.length;
    (function loop() {
        if (i--) setTimeout(loop, duration[i]);
    })();
      ^^
}
```

Comment: thank you for your detailed, thoughtful answer. I'll attempt one or more your solutions in a few moments, and let you know how it goes. Also, thank you for your time and effort, and providing helpful feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the for-loop iterates without waiting for the setTimeout to complete.
I recommend using a bit of recursion like this

```js
var content = ['one','two','three','four','five'];
var duration = ['10000','10000','20000','10000','30000'];
var i = 0;
var loop = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    if(++i < content.length);
      loop();
  },parseInt(duration[i]));
}
```

Comment: Why would it be necessary (in the original code) to "wait for the setTimeout to complete"? The original code works just fine.

Comment: But who calls `loop` the first time?

Comment: @GregHewgill Because that may be what the OP intended, an entirely reasonable, and most likely, correct assumption, although proper protocol might have been to clarify that in a comment before responding. The OP stated clearly that the original code **did not** "work just fine", although granted he failed to explain well in what exact way it didn't or what he wanted. So in that case, can we help him clarify his problem statement, instead of down-voting him into oblivion?

Comment: @torazaburo: Indeed, the OP has not explained what the code is actually supposed to do. (For the record, I did not downvote, rather I tried to help improve the question.)